# Не работает Distinct в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

пытаюсь составить такой запрос для вывода данных, где хочу вывести на экран бригаду, имя и фамилию работника, адрес, тип работы, дату начала и конца работы, имя транспорт, количество и цену транспорта и также для материалов и инструментов.

Вот, оно по идее должно вывести данные в 4 строчки, а выводит в 32. По тестил и узнал, что - это все происходит после указания в SELECT *transport.name, transport_work.amount,transport_work.price,material.name, material_work.amount,material_work.price,
instrument.name, instrument_work.amount,instrument_work.price*, а до указания их все работала правильно.

После чего я вспомнил про DISTINCT, но он мне не помог к сожалению. Кто может подсказать в чем может быть причина ?

```
select distinct team.name,user1.last_name,user1.first_name,object1.address,work1.type_of_work,work1.start_date,work1.completion_date,
transport.name, transport_work.amount,transport_work.price,material.name, material_work.amount,material_work.price,
instrument.name, instrument_work.amount,instrument_work.price
from user1
join employee on  employee.user_id  = user1.user_id
join team on    employee.team_id = team.team_id
join team_object on team_object.team_id = team.team_id
join object1 on  team_object.object_id = object1.object_id
join work1 on work1.team_object_id = team_object.team_object_id
join instrument_work on instrument_work.work_id = work1.work_id
join material_work on material_work.work_id = work1.work_id
join transport_work on transport_work.work_id = work1.work_id
join transport on transport_work.transport_id = transport.transport_id
join material on material_work.material_id = material.material_id
join instrument on instrument_work.instrument_id = instrument.instrument_id
```

Comment: Если DISTINCT не помогает, значит строки отличаются в каких-то полях, смотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Да, может быть так что из ста полей одно поле не совпадает - выводятся обе строки. Посмотри глазами что не совпадает и попробуй удалить из селекта этот столбец - будет одна строка..

Comment: Если после join вам вдруг понадобился distinct - то совсем не join вам был нужен. А `exists`.

Comment: А какая у вас СУБД? Зачем вы указали три метки? Если у вас вопрос по стандрту SQL, то не надо вообще приводить какие-то конкретные СУБД.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. DISTINCT работает по всем ячейкам в строке в случае JOIN. Чтобы он заработал правильно и красиво, я бы на вашем месте использовал WITH, а в итоговом запросе уже DISTINCT. Но это так. Личное мнение.